# showing error while running the app

Tags: android-studio

The Error is as below:

> 02-11 13:24:31.561 5262-5262/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.example.vicky.project, PID: 5262
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.vicky.project/com.example.vicky.project.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.EditText
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.EditText
>                                                        at com.example.vicky.project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this carefully
{`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText at com.example.vicky.project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)` }

You may did this 
{`TextView tv = (EditText/*change this to TextView*/) findViewById (R.id.textView)`}
If you are sure your code is correct then change ID of view in layout.xml then clean project from under the build options and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Class cast Exception because you're trying to cast TextView to EditText.